# Disable/Enable Image loading Onclick- Webview Android

Tags: android, image, webview, onclick

how to disable or enable

```
webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
```

on Button click in android?

Answer (score 0):

Put this inside of a button listener.

Example solution:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.content_layout_id);

        final Button button   = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
        final WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview_id);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Toggle image autoload
                boolean autoLoad = webView.getSettings().getLoadsImagesAutomatically();
                webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(!autoLoad);  
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: He asked how to invoke that method on a button click. The *answer* is to put inside of a button listener. If someone would like to add an *example* that would also be helpful.

Comment: I don't say your post is wrong, it's just low quality. A proper answer should provide a *solution*, not just a commentary. In fact, the reason why you see my comment is because your answer was flagged by somebody as “low quality”, and my comment has been generated by the system when I confirmed that flag.